# Powershell exit code from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm having an issue capturing exit codes when launching a Powershell window via command.

I have a windows service that at various intervals will launch a new process to execute a Powershell script. Business requirements dictate that these Powershell scripts must be separate from the actual service.
These scripts need to output an error code to be captured so retries and completions can be tracked accordingly within the service.

I'm using `System.Diagnostics.Process` to launch the Powershell scripts via this code.

```
string command = "/V:ON /c powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -file ";
command += "\"" + scriptPath + "\" ^& echo !ERRORLEVEL! ";

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Logger.LogDebug(output)
```

Within the powershell scripts themselves I am using `exit ##` to exit the script and return an error code.

Example powershell:

```
write-host "Hi "
exit 10
```

Using this simple test the `output` string is equal to just `Hi`. The `10` is left off completely. I expect to see `Hi 10`.

If I change the launching command to the following then an error code is successfully added but it's always `0`.

```
string command = "/c powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -file ";
command += "\"" + scriptPath + "\" & echo %ERRORLEVEL% ";
```

For further testing I've run both commands in a separate batch file to see the output directly and the results are not the same.

---

**Command:**

```
cmd /V:ON /c powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -file "test.ps1" ^& echo !ERRORLEVEL! 
pause
```

**Returns:**

[image: Command1]:

Which is what I'm expecting

---

**Command:**

```
cmd /c powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -file "test.ps1" & echo %ERRORLEVEL% 
pause
```

**Returns:**

[image: Command2]

As expected with this command `ERRORLEVEL` does not return the current commands error. If the particular command is ran again then the error code from the previous iteration is returned.

---

I feel like I'm likely missing something simple with grabbing the correct error code from the process in the windows service but have not been able to crack this yet.

Any suggestions?

**Thanks a bunch!**

Comment: Why not `p.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -file";`? Then you get your exit code directly from Process.ExitCode.

Comment: Hmm, that is true. I am using `cmd.exe` due to this process needing to also handle other file types as well but I could easily refactor to launch `powershell.exe` directly like that for `.ps1` files. I'll try it out.

Comment: I concur wit Quantic - you are getting the process exit code of the command shell, which is 0 (OK), not the process the command shell is running. Its far simpler to execute the process directly as suggested.

Comment: @Quantic Yep, that worked exactly as needed. I feel dumb for overlooking such an obvious solution but that's how it is sometimes. If you want to post that as an answer I'd be happy to upvote and accept. Thanks!

Comment: An important detail in Quantic's answer that I had missed - use `-File` instead of `-Command`.